# How can I check if I have added a node in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

If I use `self.addChild(node)`, is there a way that I can check later on if `node` has been added to `self`?

Comment: What? I think you need to add more context.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `parent` property to check the parent node:

```
yourNode.parent
```

If there isn't a parent, it will return `nil`.

To unwrap the parent and to check if the parent is your `self` you can use `if let`:

```
if let parentNode = node.parent{
    if parentNode == self{
       //Parent is your self
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is why you should give a node a name. There's a `childNodeWithName:` method that you can call to ask whether there is a child node with a certain name.

See also the Advanced Searches section of the SKNode documentation for other ways to find out what children you've got.